# geom_area using rainbow color scale

Tags: geom-area

I want to make the graph below. I want to make the same graph in terms of color and shape. I used the code below, but I did not get any results. Can you help me? Where is my mistake? My knowledge is weak, I would appreciate it if you would take it into consideration.

year <- seq(1965,2022,1)

> jan=c(-0.6,0.48,0.73,0.61,0.42,-0.24,-2.54,0.02,0.49,-0.89,-0.62,1.39,-0.36,1.02,-0.65,0.45,0.43,0.44,-0.13,-0.28,0.81,0.74,2.05,1.01,-1.92,0.12,1.16,1.07,-0.36,0.23,0.41,-0.05,-2.07,-0.44,-2.46,1.23,-1.97,-0.03,-1.7,-0.62,-0.9,-0.02,-0.28,-0.24,-1.28,0.89,-0.48,-0.2,1.01,0.67,0.57,1.79,0.69,0.19,0.45,-1.33,0.9,0.71)
> feb=c(0.62,-0.72,0.16,-0.69,0.65,1.02,0.6,-0.46,-0.03,-1.26,0.92,0.93,-0.1,0.35,0,-0.33,-0.33,-0.19,0.06,0.17,3.52,0.59,1.67,0.88,-2.17,0.39,0.37,2.67,0.58,1.15,-1.24,-0.16,0.02,-0.75,-0.06,0.21,0.35,-1.24,0.16,-0.93,-1.72,-0.86,-1,-0.98,-0.1,0.02,0.22,1.01,-0.45,-1.64,0.93,-0.24,-1.51,-1.01,0.3,0.3,0.15,-1.36)
> mar=c(-0.49,-0.99,0.21,-0.33,1.62,-1.15,-0.21,-0.39,0.9,-0.54,-0.5,-1.47,0.88,0.06,-0.02,0.69,0.57,1.36,0.19,1.51,0.56,-0.11,0.81,0.44,-1.48,-2.13,1.48,-1.15,-0.51,-0.08,0.56,-0.12,0.21,0.16,0.58,-0.61,1,0.06,-0.74,-1.18,-0.11,-1.27,-0.6,-3.88,0.48,-0.17,0.1,0.22,0.19,-0.15,0.97,-0.18,-1,1.3,0.69,0.92,1.73,1.5)
> apr=c(-0.39,-0.07,0.18,-0.8,0,-1.71,-0.04,-0.2,-0.66,0.91,-0.79,1.7,0.25,1.44,-0.66,-0.29,0.19,0.55,-0.84,0.56,-0.52,0.55,0.7,0.26,-1.3,0.58,0.44,-2.28,0.37,0.47,1.36,1.52,-0.2,0.22,-0.38,-0.17,0.59,1.41,-0.14,-0.33,0.68,1.39,1.52,-1.8,0.45,1.7,1.19,-0.37,-0.11,-1.48,-0.15,-0.68,-0.61,-1.32,-0.14,1.51,-2.97,-1.12)
> may=c(-1.78,0.73,0.31,0.03,-1.7,-1.32,0.08,1.1,-0.52,-0.5,0.94,0.04,-0.02,-0.38,0.73,-1.06,0.06,-0.4,1.5,1.16,-1.54,1.02,-2.36,2.09,-2.66,-0.16,0.56,0.54,1.36,0.79,0.24,-0.48,-0.96,1.25,-1.15,0.33,1.61,0.38,-0.48,0.94,-0.04,-0.97,0.03,0.34,-0.19,1.97,0.31,-0.53,0.29,-0.23,-0.94,0.5,0.19,0.81,-0.48,-0.26,-1.44,0.45)
> jun=c(0.95,-1.69,-0.14,0.29,-0.63,-2.11,-0.32,0.88,-0.96,-1.1,0.58,0.78,-0.11,1.59,0.87,-0.35,2.4,-0.34,0.49,-0.76,-0.39,0.93,-0.46,0.92,-0.69,0.79,0.9,1.64,0.67,0.38,1.22,0.35,-1.41,-0.39,0,-1.38,-1.56,0.91,0.2,-0.65,0.34,-1.85,1.04,-0.26,1.67,-0.73,0.99,-0.3,-0.45,-0.31,-0.42,0.38,-0.79,1.03,-0.19,0.12,-2.03,0.32)
> jul=c(1.8,0.59,1.19,-0.23,-1.08,-0.01,-2.11,0.48,1.1,-1.06,-0.94,1.06,0.73,-1.39,0.51,-0.77,-0.23,0.28,-0.57,-0.66,0.25,0.39,-0.61,0.3,0.24,-0.72,0.78,-1.12,0.7,-1.34,-0.02,-0.09,-0.04,0.09,1.03,-0.58,0.67,0.76,-0.12,-0.75,-0.72,1.14,0.46,-0.46,1.99,-0.16,0.47,1.71,-0.48,0.1,-1.4,2.46,-0.89,-0.82,-0.02,0.91,0.61,-2.11)
> aug=c(-0.05,-0.67,1.93,0.22,-0.16,0.65,0.28,0.18,-1.48,1.65,-1.48,-0.77,0.79,-1.35,-0.47,-0.89,1.21,-0.12,0.47,-1.09,-1.13,-0.14,-0.05,2.15,-0.67,-0.1,0.62,1.34,0.54,-1.02,-0.61,-1.25,0.38,0.7,-1.48,-0.61,0.39,-0.17,0.87,-0.41,-0.51,-0.81,1.64,0.09,1.08,0.96,1.14,-0.53,0.45,0.22,2.01,-1.06,0.35,0.43,-1.09,0.92,-0.97,-1.48)
> sep=c(-0.04,1.44,1.76,1.02,0.46,-0.88,-1.48,-0.59,-1.48,0.96,0.33,0.51,-0.52,-0.23,-0.85,-0.78,-0.95,-0.74,0.46,-1.29,-1.22,0.07,-0.09,0.84,0.63,-1.48,-0.79,1.01,-1.02,-0.78,1.52,0.65,1.1,0.06,1.49,-0.38,-0.66,0.51,1.03,-0.27,-0.03,-0.26,-1.48,1.06,0.71,0.21,-0.31,1.6,0.36,2.04,-0.95,1.07,-1.41,-0.35,0.37,-1.24,0.42,0.74)
> oct=c(1.89,-1.1,-0.43,-0.6,0.53,0.34,1.47,1.54,0.06,-1.97,-0.82,0.75,0.08,-0.29,1.23,-1.08,-0.39,-0.71,0.05,0.18,-0.02,0.45,1.08,0.67,1.59,0.49,0.06,-1.38,-0.56,0.45,-0.33,0.87,0.43,-2.74,-0.66,0.38,0.61,0.1,1.5,-1.21,-0.5,1.43,-1.02,-0.25,0.01,0.72,-0.53,-0.32,-0.43,0.96,1.94,-0.57,0.78,0.52,-0.94,-2.7,-0.87,-0.36)
> nov=c(0.43,-1.62,1.15,0.57,-0.34,-0.33,0.09,0.49,0.88,0.31,0.34,-0.73,-0.72,-1.63,1.04,0.64,1.03,-0.06,1.63,0.27,-0.6,1.45,0.88,0.22,0.91,0.71,1.07,1.87,1.2,1.11,0.18,-1.82,-0.66,0.05,-1.74,-1.77,-0.14,0.05,1.13,0.65,-0.77,-0.27,0.39,-0.57,0.74,-1.82,-0.56,-0.99,0.35,-0.14,-1.66,0.3,0.75,0.74,-0.83,-0.63,-0.3,-0.56)
> dec=c(0.99,0.6,0.62,0.54,1.33,-0.1,0.65,-2.23,-0.27,-0.74,0.06,0.59,0.66,1.04,-0.51,-0.73,-0.25,-1.1,-0.64,-0.18,0.64,0.23,1.92,0.92,0.5,0.41,0.89,0.63,-1.12,0.89,-3.09,0.52,-0.21,1.31,-1.59,0.2,0.03,0.22,-0.71,-1.83,0.02,-0.99,-0.45,-0.03,0.52,-1.44,-0.85,1.8,-0.38,-0.61,-0.38,1.68,0.27,1.58,0.9,-0.73,-0.06,-1.57)
> df = data.frame(year,jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec)
> df <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "year")
> ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=variable, fill=value)) + geom_raster(aes(fill = value), interpolate = TRUE)  + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(9, 'OrRd')))[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4hN4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtHsL.jpg)

What am I missing? Where am I making the mistake?Thank you

What am I missing? Where am I making the mistake?Can you help